# What does infinite dimension mean in nonparametric method?

Tags: nonparametric

I see something like: If there is a function: Y=G(x)+error term, G() is unknown or unspecified, then G() can be viewed as functions characterized by infinite dimensional parameters. Can anyone make an example for this.
Also Why does the baseline hazard function have an infinite dimensional parameter?